# How to store large amounts of data as a value in std::map?

Tags: c++

I need to store a large amounts of trading data in my program and analyse it. I want to store my data in different deques by different keys, so, I have a map like this:

```
std::map< char, std::deque<UserDefinedType> > my_map;
```

Another way to store my data is to use shared pointers to deques:

```
std::map< char, std::shared_ptr< std::deque<UserDefinedType> > > my_map;
```

Which of these variants is preferred for performance? I have approximately ~200 keys and ~90 millions of elements in each deque for each key.

Comment: Code both, measure, pick the better performing one.  Optimizing without numbers is like forecasting the weather.  We all know how "well" that goes.

Comment: Will you ever pass the map around by value? I.e. will the map (and its data) ever be copied? If not, then it doesn't matter (and using pointers to the deque means an extra indirection that needs to be handled).

Comment: Also, remember to measure an *optimized* build, not a "debug" build or an application that was not compiled with optimizations turned on.

Comment: A `std::deque<T>` probably just has a few pointers and integers as data members. There's probably not much benefit of putting it in a shared pointer unless you actually need to share ownership.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, you are gonna store 90 million x 200 keys which is 18 billion entries. Assuming UserDefinedType is a measly 4 bytes size per entry (most likely more) that is 72 billion bytes which equates to 72 gigabytes of memory not including any of the overhead. Are you sure you would not store this on disk?

Comment: I see no reason to use `std::shared_ptr` unless user of the class isn't careful and accidentally copies the result instead of getting a reference to it. In which case you can consider usage of `std::unique_ptr` to avoid unnecessary copying.

P.S. Do you need it to be a `std::deque<T>`? Why not `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: smells like premature optimization. Storing smart pointers or instances has different semantics and at this stage you should make a decision based on that instead of speculating on performance

Answer (score 4):

If you only have a single instance of each deque, no need for `shared_ptr`. If you're building multiple RAM indices over the same data on different keys, shared pointers will help a lot.

Couple more things.

If you have 200 keys and they are single characters, this data structure is much faster, just don't forget to cast from `char` to `uint8_t` when you access it, as chars are almost always signed:

```
std::array<std::deque<UserDefinedType>, 0x100>
```

Generally, unless you need ordering for keys, prefer std::unordered_map over std::map. All mainstream compilers implement unordered maps as hash maps, std::map as a red-black tree, much slower.

Comment: Almost with you, although I'd be wary of making generalisations like "map is much slower" - it depends on too many things. Also although maps are often created as a red-black tree they are not defined by implementation but by contract and it's best to teach C++ in that manner

Comment: You're missing the point. "How things actually work" depends on the implementation chosen, yet you did not specify one, so your statement is a false generalisation. That has nothing to do with whether you "care about performance" or not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It’s implemented this way in VC++, gcc and clang. Which implementation differs from what I’ve wrote in the answer?

Comment: Ah yes, the old "show me one that does it differently" counter-argument. Still missing the point.  Oh well, never mind mate. Taking away my upvote for now because of some over-generalisations that have the potential to mislead. Ping me if corrected.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See also this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ “map containers are generally slower than unordered_map containers to access individual elements by their key”

Comment: That statement contains the word "generally", whereas you make a blanket statement without any qualification.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My answer also contains the world “generally”, what’s the difference?

Comment: It says generally prefer unordered_map. Then it makes a blanket statement about how a map is implemented, and a blanket statement saying that map is always "much slower". Sorry, I don't think I can make it any more clear to you. If you don't grok the danger of generalisations, or the concept of abstractions/standards, I cannot explain that to you in this format. Never mind. Ciao!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When all mainstream compilers are implemented in one particular way, and have been for decades, what’s the “danger” of generalization?